# Find and replace with lookup file

Tags: c#

I want to find and replace text in a textfile with a lookup file.

Currently i use the following code to replace a single string:

```
System.IO.StreamReader objReader;
objReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(someTextFile);
string content = objReader.ReadToEnd();
objReader.Close();

content = content.Replace("Text1", "Replacetext1");

System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(someTextFile);
objWriter.Write(content);
objWriter.Close();
```

I want to use a csv file for lookup. The format of this file is:

> Text1, Replacedtext1
>   Text2, Replacedtext2
>   Text3, Replacedtext3
>   etc...

Who can me give some tips?

Thanks

Comment: You really should try some code yourself rather than asking us to write it for you.  But an alternative approach might be to use a 3pp library for CSV files such as this one:  https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: That's a bit broad for a question. What in particular is making you hit a wall? (Try reading [ask] to improve your question , maybe)

Comment: In general you have these Tasks still to do: 1. Read in the csv - probably into a List<Tuple<string,string>> or a List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> or something alike. 2. amend above code so that the replace line is called in a loop that iterates the list.

Comment: Mind that if you do design your csv as shown above,neither search nor replacement text can contain ",".

Comment: just to be clear here, you want to look into the lookup file, then take the first word from the first line -> then run through another file and replace all occurences of that word with the replacement that is written in the lookup file ? Is that correct?

Comment: Hi, thanks four the reactions. I just started programming and started a beginners course. I'm not asking you to write the code for me, but i'm asking for tips. Beacause there is maybe too much information on the internet for a beginner.     @MongZhu yes, your assumption is correct.

Comment: @JohnPst I wrote you a couple of tip. Hope it is enough for you to solve your problem. If not, drop me a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Here are some tips:

1) use

```
string [] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("yourLookUpFilePathHere");
```

it will return all lines in a string array. The same you can do with your file in which you want to make the replacements. Now you can loop through the look up file.

2) At each position / line in the array you can use the method:

```
string [] partsOfLine = allLines[i].Split('hereYourSeparatorAsChar');
```

3) now if you have fiddled out the first word you can start a second loop to look for matches in the replacement file and there you can use the line from your code:

```
allLinesOfReplaceFile[i] = allLinesOfReplaceFile[i].Replace("Text1", "Replacetext1");
```

I hope you get the drift, if it is still unclear then drop me a comment

Comment: Thanks a lot!  With these tips I could build what I wanted.

Comment: No Problem, I am glad I could help :)